# Windows GUI program to list files in a .tar.Z (.TAZ) compressed archive file?

Tags: zip

Windows Explorer can display the contents of a .zip file.

I have a Unix system that writes backup.tar.Z files (it pipes tar output through traditional compress - not gzip) as BACKUP.TAZ onto USB Flash memory sticks.

I'd like an easy way to examine those under Windows.

I could install GNU gzip or other command-line tools but some people prefer GUI programs.

Is there a native or 3rd-party Windows GUI program that would provide a list of files in the compressed archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a [lot of programs that can open .taz extension](http://extension.nirsoft.net/taz) like 7-Zip, WinRAR, WinZip.